# insert into with sequence oracle

Tags: oracle, sequence

I have following query in Oracle:

```
INSERT INTO table2 
(ID,Name,Address,MOL)
SELECT table2.ID,table2.Name,table2.Address,’sometext’
FROM table2
WHERE table2.ID=1000;
```

I want to implement this query when column ID have `sequence` called *mysequence*.
Does someone know solution?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

```
INSERT INTO table2 
(ID,Name,Address,MOL)
SELECT mysequence.nextval,table2.Name,table2.Address,’sometext’
FROM table2
WHERE table2.ID=1000;
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to create a trigger that inserts the next sequence value:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER myschema.table2_ins_trg
   BEFORE INSERT ON myschema.table2 FOR EACH ROW
   WHEN (New.ID IS NULL) 
BEGIN
  SELECT myschema.mysequence.Nextval INTO :New.ID FROM dual;
END;
```

Then you leave off the ID when inserting:

```
INSERT INTO table2 
  (Name, Address, MOL)
SELECT table2.Name, table2.Address, 'sometext'
  FROM table2
 WHERE table2.ID = 1000;
```

I like this method because if I make inserts with a GUI tool, I can leave the ID blank and it will automatically be filled with the next sequence value.